# Postgres: How to clear transaction ID for anonymity and data reduction

Tags: database, postgresql, transactions

We're running an evaluation platform where users can comment on certain things. A key feature is that people can comment only once, and every comment is made in anonymity.

We're using Postgres for all our data. We want to save a flag in the database that a user created a comment (so they cannot comment again). In a separate table but within the same transaction, we want to save the comment itself without any link to the user.

However, postgres saves the transaction ID of every tuple inserted into the database (`xmin` of the [system columns](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-system-columns.html)). So now there's a link between the user and their comment which we have to avoid!

**Possible (Non)Solutions**

- Vacuuming alone does not help as it does not clear the transaction ID. See the "Note" box in the "24.1.5. Preventing Transaction ID Wraparound Failures" section [in the postgres docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/routine-vacuuming.html).
- Putting those inserts in different transactions, doesn't really solve anything since transaction IDs are consecutive.
- We could aggregate comments from multiple users to one large text in the database with some separators, but since old versions of this large text would be kept by postgres at least until the next vacuum, that doesn't seem like a full solution. Also, we'd still have the order of when the user added their comment, which would be nice to not save as well.
- Re-writing all the tuples in those tables periodically (by a dummy UPDATE to all of them), followed by a vacuum would probably erase the "insert history" sufficiently, but that too seems like a crude hack.

Is there any other way within postgres to make it impossible to reconstruct the insertion history of a table?

Comment: On the one hand you say that you want to avoid a user commenting twice, which requires a way to link users to comments, on the other hand you say you don't want such links. Obviously you cannot have both. Can you clarify that?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe: Thanks! So we need to know whether or not a user commented, and obviously we need all the comments that were made, but we must not know which user made which comment. This is to fulfil the requirements "people can comment only once, and every comment is made in anonymity". To do that, we can simply give the user a flag "already commented on X", and separately save the comment without a link to the user. I edited the question to hopefully make this separation more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could use something like [`dblink`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/dblink.html) or [`postgres_fdw`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/postgres-fdw.html) to write to tables using a remote connection (either to the current database or another database), and thereby separate `xmin` values, even though you as a user think you are doing it all in the "same transaction."

Regarding the concerns about tracking via reverse-engineering sequential xmin values, since dblink is asynchronous, this issue may become moot at scale, when many users are simultaneously adding comments to the system. This might not work if you need to be able to rollback after encountering an error—it really depends on how important it is for you to confine the operations into one transaction.

Comment: Forwarding to another database would effectively split the one transaction into multiple, right? If that's the case, I think this would "obfuscate" things but, since the transaction IDs are sequential, it would still be rather easy to correlate those transactions and find out which one happened right after another one, no?

Regarding this becoming moot at scale: We're not building the system "at scale" :) It's about one thousand users and will never grow by orders of magnitude. There are never many users creating comments at the same time.

Comment: It is rather important to let users comment exactly one time. Splitting the transaction without the atomicity guarantee, possibly allowing users to vote zero or two times when errors happen, would be a pretty deep flaw in a core feature of the software.

Comment: If you store the comments and user-commented history in separate database instances (initdb) on the same server, and link them together with dblink or postgres_fdw, their xmin will never be related, and yet you would be able to query the two tables as if they were in the same database

Comment: If I understand correctly, the xmin of those two tables in separate instances is still related since they are sequential. Since each comment has one entry in the user-commented history, you take all the comments, sort by xmin, take all the user-commented-flags, sort them by their (different) xmins, and put those two sorted lists side by side. The result would be the same, it's just harder to get. Or have I misunderstood something?

Comment: Why can't you put the user's comment history in an array?  For every `posts` the user commented on, append the `post_id` into the array (and maybe even shuffle the array--and use UUIDS instead of a sequence to identify `posts`).  Then there's a one-to-many relationship between the user's profile/history and the set of `posts`.  On the database where the profile/history lives, there's only one `xmin` related to the user, and on the `posts` database, there's a large list of `xmins` that can no longer be correlated to the profile/history table

Comment: I think that is similar to the third option in the original post: aggregating either the comments or, as you suggested, the comment history, would solve the problem after a vacuum. before vacuum, old versions of that array would still be contained in the database. That again would make it harder to reconstruct the information, but not impossible. But yeah, with frequent vacuums that would be feasible. Using an array makes this a little more convenient, so thanks for that.

Comment: I guess you could vacuum after every write to the comment history table as part of the operation--get rid of the evidence immediately...  Not to mention that there *should* be sufficient activity on one database  to skew the `xmin` so that it cannot be correlated with the `xmin` sequence of the other database (i.e., user login activity, inserts into the `posts` table, vacuums initiated by autovacuum, etc.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202069/discussion-between-richyen-and-karyon).

Answer (score -1):

I don't think there is a problem.

In your comment you write that you keep a flag with the user (however exactly you store it) that keeps track of which posting the user commented on. To keep that information private, you have to keep that flag private so that nobody except the user itself could read it.

If no other user can see that information, then no other user can see the `xmin` on the corresponding table entries. Then nobody could make a correlation with the `xmin` on the comment, so the problem is not there.

The difficult part is how you want to keep the information private which postings a user commented on. I see two ways:

1. Don't use database techniques to do it, but write the application so that it hides that information from the users.
2. Use PostgreSQL Row Level Security to do it.

There is no way you can keep the information from a superuser. Don't even try.

Comment: Apart from admins, there's only one database user for the web server. The web server of course does not access the xmin column at all (the flag is also shown only to the respective user). So indeed no other user can see that information, but in my understanding this is not how data avoidance works: The point is not to prevent unauthorized access to the data, but to not have the data in the first place so it cannot possibly be used for unintended purposes. This even includes a fix for the superuser problem :)

Comment: The flag whether a user commented at all is not as sensitive and required for operation, so that goes into the database. The information which specific comment a user made is highly sensitive and not required for operation, so that shouldn't be in the database, that's how I see it.

Comment: @karyon: well the information which comment a user made needs to be stored _somewhere_ and regardless of where you store it (database, filesystem, cloud, printed book) means it's available to someone and can be hacked. So by not storing that information in the database you just move the problem to a different technology, you don't avoid that problem

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: no, we don't need to store the information *which* comment a user made, only *that* they have made a comment. there are two bits of information: the flag whether a user has made a comment already so they cannot comment again (this obviously needs a link to the user), and then the comment itself (this does not need a link). so that link of the flag must be stored somewhere, true! That is in the database and not a big problem. The problem is that we do not want to store a link from the comment to the user anywhere, but that's what's postgres is doing implicitly.

Comment: If you track to which object a user made a comment (but not the comment), than how do you deal with the situation that there may be only a single comment on an object (which would identify the commenter)? Even with a handful of comments it might be easy to guess. So I don't see why you are so sensitive with the `xmin`s.

Comment: Sorry, missed that one. We are considering deleting all comments when not enough comments are made in a certain time period. Even if we wouldn't do that, a hard-to-fix edge case shouldn't stop us from fixing the general case in my opinion.

Comment: Hm. There will always be a first comment. If I have full access to the database, I can monitor that and always figure out who made the first comments.

Answer (score -1):

You could store the users with their flags and the comments on different database clusters (and use distributed transactions), then the `xmin`s would be unrelated.

Make sure to disable `track_commit_timestamp`.

To make it impossible to correlate the transactions in the databases, you could issue random

```
SELECT txid_current();
```

which do nothing but increment the transaction counter.

Comment: thanks. I think this is basically @richyen's answer, and I think it does not solve the problem.

Comment: It is essentially the same, but your fears are unfounded: there is no way to relate transaction IDs of different database clusters. I still think that yours is a non-problem. You didn't answer the questions in my comment to my other answer. I think that your setup is always vulnerable to attacks by superusers, and the transaction IDs are not your biggest problem.

Comment: If I understood correctly, they can be related, since they are sequential. If you get all the flags with their user, sort them by xmin, get all comments, sort those by xmin, you have two lists of equal length which should directly correspond to one another. Or am I wrong?

This is also the scenario we want to defend against: That an attacker gets hold of the database contents. Currently that would allow them to de-anonymize all the comments. Superusers can do that easily as well, sure, but there are exactly two of those and they are considered trustworthy.

Comment: Why are you worried about xmins that are vaguely related, when it can be directly seen from the data on which item a user commented? With few comments on an item, that is almost as good as having the user's name on the comment.

Comment: The xmin-problem applies always, so we really do want to fix that. The few-comment-problem exists only if, well, there are only a few comments on an item. That does not happen often, and if it happens, we're considering deleting the comments altogether.

Comment: You can easily break the connection between xmins if you just randomly run `SELECT txid_current();` all the time. These don't do much but consume a transaction ID.

Comment: that does not change the ordering of the relevant transactions, which is all that's needed for correlation.

Comment: Your efforts are futile. There is always the transaction log which contains everything that happened, so you can dig the order of events out from there with some effort. You cannot do without a transaction log, otherwise you cannot restore the database if necessary. At that level of paranoia, perhaps `pg_dump` the database everyday, drop it, scrub the disk and restore it from the dump. That would destroy all traces of order.